# Returning Hapi FHIR element in restful server

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I have a basic springboot application set up that'll return string values on get calls, but when I try to return a mock Patient object I get a weird error

My code:

```
@RequestMapping("/test2")
Patient test2(){
    Patient patient = new Patient();
    patient.setId("1");
    patient.addName().setFamily("Bar").addGiven("Foo").addGiven("M");
    patient.addAddress().addLine("Address Line 1");
    patient.addAddress().setCity("City Name");
    patient.addAddress().setCountry("Country Name");
    patient.addTelecom().setValue("555-555-1111");

    return patient;
}
```

The Error seems to be that the created json is recursive and never ending. A snippet of the response is:

```
{"formatCommentsPre":[],"formatCommentsPost":[],"id":"1","meta":{"formatCommentsPre":[],"formatCommentsPost":[],"id":null,"extension":[],"versionId":null,"lastUpdated":null,"profile":[],"security":[],"tag":[],"empty":true,"tagFirstRep":{"formatCommentsPre":[],"formatCommentsPost":[],"id":null,"extension":[],"system":null,"version":null,"code":null,"display":null,"userSelected":false,"empty":true,"displayElement":{"formatCommentsPre":[],"formatCommentsPost":[],"id":null,"extension":[],"valueNotNull":"","primitive":true,"empty":true,"value":null,"valueAsString":null,"idElement":{"formatCommentsPre":[],"formatCommentsPost":[],"id":null,"extension":[],"valueNotNull":"","primitive":true,"empty":true,"value":null,"valueAsString":null,"idElement":{"formatCommentsPre":[],"formatCommentsPost":[],"id":null,"extension":[],"valueNotNull":"","primitive":true,"empty":true,"value":null,"valueAsString":null,"idElement":{"formatCommentsPre":[],"formatCommentsPost":[],"id":null,"extension":[],"valueNotNull":"","primitive":true,"empty":true,"value":null,"valueAsString":null,"idElement":{"formatCommentsPre":[],"formatCommentsPost":[],"id":null,"extension":[],"valueNotNull":"","primitive":true,"empty":true,"value":null,"valueAsString":null,"idElement":{"formatCommentsPre":[],"formatCommentsPost":[],"id":null,"extension":[],"valueNotNull":"","primitive":true,"empty":true,"value":null,"valueAsString":null,"idElement":{"formatCommentsPre":[],"formatCommentsPost":[],"id":null,"extension":[],"valueNotNull":"","primitive":true,"empty":true,"value":null,"valueAsString":null,"idElement":{"formatCommentsPre":[],"formatCommentsPost":[],"id":null,"extension":[],"valueNotNull":"","primitive":true,"empty":true,"value":null,"valueAsString":null,"idElement":{"formatCommentsPre":[],"formatCommentsPost":[],"id":null,"extension":
```

Does anybody have an idea as to what I'm doing wrong and what the correct way to send a FHIR response for a patient is?

Answer (score 1):

You should use FHIR Parser to cast your object into JSON and then return the JSON value as a simple string.

```
// Create a FHIR context
FhirContext ctx = FhirContext.forR4();

// Create a Patient resource to serialize
Patient patient = new Patient();
patient.addName().setFamily("Simpson").addGiven("James");

// Instantiate a new JSON parser
IParser parser = ctx.newJsonParser();

// Serialize it
String serialized = parser.encodeResourceToString(patient);

// Return the result
return new ResponseEntity<>(serialized, HttpStatus.OK);
```